# MSMQ read and write Methods with Asynchronous

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, msmq

i am start working with MSMQ. i find that very fast way, for solutions that need to handle millions of requests, i write a performance test and see : it write 1000000 object in only 43 second (with my pc hardware config)! i like that.
so, i need to read and write millions of messages and the performance is so important for me.
i use threading for increase speed and performance, am i wrong? is this right?
here is my code:

```
public static void WriteToQueue(List<Human> humans)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            var queue = new Queue().Prepare(queueName);
            Logger.LogInfo("Started writing to queue");
            foreach (var human in humans)
            {
                queue.Add(human.JsonSerialize());
            }
        }).Start();
    }

private static void ReadFromQueue()
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            var queue = new Queue().Prepare(queueName);
            var receivedCount = 0;
            while (receivedCount <= itemsCount)
            {
                var human = queue.Pop().JsonDeserialize<Human>();
                receivedCount++;
                if (receivedCount % 10000 == 0)
                {
                    Logger.Count(receivedCount);
                }
                if (receivedCount == itemsCount)
                {
                    watch.Stop();
                    Logger.LogInfo("Took {0} to write/read {1} times to/from queue".Fill(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, itemsCount));
                }
            }
            Queue.Delete(queueName);
        }).Start();
    }
```

and i use them :

```
        var humans = Enumerable.Range(0, itemsCount).Select(i => new Human
        {
            FirstName = "first name" + i,
            LastName = "last name" + i
        }).ToList();

        watch.Start();

        WriteToQueue(humans);

        ReadFromQueue();

        Console.ReadLine();
```

ok, its my first solution(use threading). i find async programing is the best approach (am i wrong?),i find that Asynchronous programming is beter way to do that! because this methods(read and write to msmq) is IO bound (wating for io operations)! and i am raise many threads that are waiting for io!
i am new in Asynchronous programming, can anyone help me and write for me some code to create these methods(read and write) work with Asynchronous Programming? 
and, What is the best way? (parallel.foreach - async TAP - async APM - async EAP -threading)

Comment: every body? some body? body?

Comment: ok, i find that MSMQ have BeginReceive and EndReceive that provide us to async functionality! i write a listener for receive asyncly! its good. but for sending i have not any idea! is it posible to send message to msmq asyncly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find a beter way and i like to share that.
threading is good, best way is depend on your state and your business, for me i need to work with msmq about 200 million message on a day! 
so, i get this result :
you can save about 300 milliseconds for read and write 10000 message!
you can save about 6 second for read and write 1 million message!
you can save about 60 second for read and write 10 million message!

```
class MsmqListener
{
   public void StartListening(string queuePath)
    {
        MessageQueue msQueue = new MessageQueue(@".\private$\" + queuePath);
        msQueue.ReceiveCompleted += QueueMessageReceived;
        msQueue.BeginReceive();
        // you can do averything here, its async
    }

    private void QueueMessageReceived(object source, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageQueue msQueue = (MessageQueue)source;

        //once a message is received, stop receiving
        Message msMessage = null;
        msMessage = msQueue.EndReceive(args.AsyncResult);

        //do something with the message
        //...

        //begin receiving again
        msQueue.BeginReceive();
    }
}
```

this methods(beginRecieve and endRecieve) are async methods for msmq.

Comment: Or you could just use `Task.Factory.FromAsync(msMq.BeginReceive(), msMq.EndPeek)` to give your `MessageQueue` a TAP-friendly API

Comment: hi kirill, thank you . you help me always. i see your code sample in my last question, and i want to find somethig diferent. i am calculating all ways to do it for my benchmark. thanx alot.